# My SQL workbench database is not updating when html form is submitted

Tags: php, html, mysql-workbench

I made a HTML form to link it to mysql workbench. The form or the php connection codes are not showing any errors but the changes arent reflected in the database. I have deleted some of the code which isn't important since the site doesn't allow me.

### HTML FORM CODE

```
<form action="qrconnect.php" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="Name">
            </div>
            .
            .
            .
            <div class="button">
                <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

### PHP code

```
<?php

include_once("connect.php");
include_once("qr.html");

/*Data from the html form is on the right. The objects that will be composed of that data is on the left.*/
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Name =  $_POST['Name'];
    $EMail = $_POST['E-mail']; 
    $Phone= $_POST['Phone'];
    $Designation =$_POST['Designation'];
    $Dept= $_POST['Dept'];

if (mysqli_connect_error())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit(); 
}
 mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO schema1.emp_table(Name,E-mail,Phone,Designation,Dept)
    VALUES('$Name','$EMail','$Phone','$Designation','$Dept')");
    echo"<font color='green'>Data added successfully";
  }
?>
```

### PHP Connect code

```
   <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $port=3306;
    $socket="";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="schema1";

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, 
     $socket)
              or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());
        //$con->close();

?>
```

Comment: please make sure you use lover case when operating database
make your column name small

Comment: why dbname is blank in connection string?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections....

Comment: the dbname is added in the code.just didnt add here.that part is fine

Comment: also ik about the sql injection. But will worry about that part when the basic connection is fine.